# Rerender of ApplicationView - contextualElement is missing

Tags: ember.js

I came across weird issue during rerendering of ApplicationView.

So I have following code in ApplicationView which cares about rerender:

```
languageChanged: function() {
    this.rerender();
}.observes('App.i18nResource')
```

which causes following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Required contextualElement for view <App.ApplicationView:ember676> is missingember.js:3865
Ember.assertember.js:10627 
Renderer_renderTreeember.js:41082 (anonymous function)
DeferredActionQueues.invokeember.js:749 
DeferredActionQueues.flushember.js:135 
Backburner.endember.js:521 (anonymous function)
```

I have question whether you know where could be a problem or can you explain me what contextualElement is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that it tries to rerender the view before it even rendered its context. The `contextualElement` is representing your views **parent** DOM object (which should fall back to the documents `body` element) as needed by ember metal-views [renderer.js #L58-68](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal-views/lib/renderer.js#L58-68)

To solve your problem it may be worth a try to make sure the view got rendered already by scheduling your `this.rerender()` call like this:

```
Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() { this.rerender() })
```

Comment: This is not my case. My application is fully rendered and rerender on ApplicationView is called if user clicks to button to change language in app. This button performs Ajax to get language from server which is then set to App by App.set('i18resource', language); And as you can see in code in my top question there is observer to i18resource which performs that rerender function.
I've also tried looping through Ember.View.views and rerender each view and everything except ApplicationView was good. On ApplicationView I've got same error. Do you have some other clue where could be issue?